# Apache solr not work with special character for search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr

I am creating search query for filter my data it not filter as per my expectation
my query string is :Reinvestment Act of 2009 - RD&D
its not return me any result 
after replace string : Reinvestment Act of 2009 / RD&D
its working fine.
is there any limitation at solr search if yes then which special char are not allowed.
what alternative to search using special character using solr

Answer (score 1):

Solr query parsers treat certain characters specially. For example, `-` means exclude the next term in the Solr Query Parser syntax. You can escape these special characters with a backslash, or enclose them in quotes.

You can find more information in the [Solr query documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax).